# Removing decimals from the numbers

Tags: java

```
public static String convertCentimeterToHeight(double d) {
    double feetPart = 0;
    double inchesPart = 0;
    if (String.valueOf(d) != null && String.valueOf(d).trim().length() != 0) {
        feetPart = (int) Math.floor((d / 2.54) / 12);
        inchesPart = (int) Math.ceil((d / 2.54) - (feetPart * 12));
    }
    return (String.valueOf(feetPart)) + "' " + String.valueOf(inchesPart) + "''";
}
```

I am trying to remove decimals, but i am still getting something like this `5.0' 6.0"`. When we do a `String.value() on a variable` does it remove the decimals and give me the exact number?

Comment: use ints. why do you use doubles to store ints?

Comment: why not using "casting"?

Comment: agree, why don't you use Integer.parseInt instead?

Comment: people are too stupid or too intelligent for this , he is asking the case 5.4 to 54 :/

Comment: Two minor things: 1. for the inches, use `round`, not `ceil`, for more sensible values. 2. you don't need to do your null check on `d`, because a `double` is a primitive, and primitives are never null.

Comment: if that's what he want, then he can use replace method.
but if it's to convert to integer, casting is one of ways to do it.

Comment: How would `String.valueOf(double)` ever return a null? or an empty string? Remove these pointless tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you want to store  `int`s in `feetPart` and `inchesPart` variables, just declare them as `int`s :

```
int feetPart = 0;
int inchesPart = 0;
```

Then you'll avoid them being displayed as `double`s (i.e. with the trailing `.0`).

Answer (score 3):

You can simply cast it into an `int`.

```
(int) d;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the double variables to an int

```
return (String.valueOf((int)feetPart)) + "' " + 
String.valueOf((int)inchesPart) + "''";
```

That should fix it as well.

Answer (score 1):

For your information.

```
// always true, it never returns null
String.valueOf(d) != null 
// always true, a double is never an empty string.
String.valueOf(d).trim().length() != 0; 

// same as
int feetPart = (int) (d / 2.54 / 12);
int inchesPart = ((int) (d / 2.54)) % 12;

// same as
return feetPart + "' " + inchesPart + "\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

all the answer replace your variable type.
my way keeps.
only use these codes you will find the magic.

```
double d = 1.0d;
String s = String.format("%1$.0f", d);
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: you could refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html to learn how to us java format.

Comment: also the String.format will handle the null exception or illegal exception automatically. if you use TYPE CONVERSION you should handle it by yourself. that's not convenient.

Comment: You are using a hammer to crack a nut. This is hundreds of times as inefficient as a simple `(int)` cast.